# Is there a way to use my digital pen as a slide show clicker for my beamer slides?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I've recently purchased a digital pen, and one of the big selling points is that you can use your pen as a slide show clicker while giving a PowerPoint presentation.  I use beamer for my slides, and I'd like to be able to use the pen to navigate my presentation.  Is there any way to add that command to my onboard pdf viewer (I use TeXstudio), or is there some other app that I could present the pdf and use that feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably it will work with a pdf viewer like SumatraPDF, AdobeReader or similars, but I have no idea about TeXstudio viewer. Did you try it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about TeX/LaTeX or related systems,